# Remove the faq popup

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-users

[image: The FAQ popup.]

While the FAQ popup bar might be helpful to new users, it quickly gets annoying having to close it when browsing yet another SE site. Would it be possible to either not show it, or, only show it once globally (e.g. with an external javascript file)?

Comment: I would be curious to find out the hit rate through that link (i.e., # clicks / # hits that show the banner).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it isn't shown any more. Instead, it has been replaced with a smaller, more tastefully-integrated banner:

[image: Take the tour!]

Answer (score 5):

A gigantic, resounding **NO**.

The FAQ is **NOT** the same, depending on which site you are. I don't care if you can recite SO's FAQ by heart, it doesn't mean you are able to tell me if you can ask smartphone or website questions on Super User. And same goes for all future SE sites.

If you see this popup, it means that this is potentially your first time here, because you have no account there. And as such, yes, you should read the FAQ. Because no matter how much reputation you have on one site, you are still in need to read the FAQ on another one, to know what kind of questions should be asked there or not.

---

That said, if you only want a client-side solution, then it's ok, it's your own business. But for now, your question hints at cutting this server-side.

Comment: the good news is, the "different" stuff is always at the *top* of the `/faq` -- so just read the first few paragraphs and skip the "rules" part.

Answer (score 4):

May be add a cookie called `m=1` in stackexchange sites?

**Edit**: Here is a greasemonkey script that add m=1 to all stackexchange sites by checking meta tag

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

Code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Add a Cookie
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @include        *
// ==/UserScript==

meta=document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
for(i in meta){
 if (/^StackExchange /.test(meta[i].content)){
  document.cookie="m=1";
  break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this technically possible? I don't think e.g. https://superuser.com/ can tell that the FAQ was dismissed on https://stackoverflow.com/, even if they both source a common Javascript file